# Split Stripe order for two separate recipients

Tags: php, laravel, payment

Can't add Stripe as a tag, but we will need to use it for this element of functionality.

Scenario:
We take an order through our site. We want to receive 50% of the order, and we want another designated party to receive the remaining 50%, with Stripe.

Is this feasible?

A solution to this may be:
We receive 100% of the order. 50% of this total is transferred from our Stripe account to the designated party. This would need to happen as part of the checkout process ie. via the Stripe API, and not manually via the Stripe admin interface in the account area.

Please can somebody give us some advice on this? Is it feasible at all? What would be a logical approach to handling this?

The crux of this issue is:
We want payments made by the customer to be 'split' between account A (our account) and account B (somebody else's account).

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried collecting stripe fees? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might work.
The following is from the [stripe PHP api reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_transfer)

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_5bmIJBkXxfzTBq89mij6R3Mn");

\Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
"amount" => 400,
"currency" => "usd",
"destination" => "acct_1AAhQBKQM0dv8TmS",
"transfer_group" => "ORDER_95"
```

I think that you change the amount line to...

```
"amount" => (PLACE A PHP VARIABLE FOR PRICE HERE * 50).floor,
```